# Is it possible running websockets as backgroud in python?

Tags: python, websocket

I hope websockets can running in background.

1. Once received the message, print it.
2. Other function can call it's 'send' function to send message

But the code under 'loop.run_until_complete(Iao())' will no running.

I tried use 'threading' then put websockets in other thread, it's still can't running.

Is it possible to achieve it? except create a async function

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

class WebsocketHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = None

    async def connect(self, url):
        self.conn = await websockets.connect(url)

    async def send(self, msg):
        await self.conn.send(msg)
    
    async def receive(self):
        while True:
            print(await self.conn.recv())

    async def close(self):
        await self.conn.close()


async def Iao():
    global handler
    handler = WebsocketHandler()
    await handler.connect('ws://localhost:8765')

    await handler.receive()
    await handler.send('{"action":"plus"}')
    await handler.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(Iao())

while True:
    print("1")
    asyncio.run(handler.send('{"action":"plus"}'))
    print("2")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: If you want to run additional code in asyncio, you should put it into a coroutine `async def` and add it as a task. You can also add it to `Iao()`. And make sure to use `asyncio.sleep()`.

Comment: Is only way to implement it by creating a async function?

Comment: You could run the event loop in another thread, but it adds a lot of complexity if your websocket is async and the rest of the code is not.